# How to check not starts with condition in if statement?

Tags: shell-script

I want to check the condition like below. Line should not starts with `#`
symbol:

```
if[ ! ["$Line" == "#*"] ]; then
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 11):

There are many problems in your snippet, but basically the syntax `[![...]]` is not valid, in the bash (and many other shells) `[[` is a single command, which cannot be split by any other character.

You can negate equality operator instead:

```
if [[ "$LINE" != \#* ]]; then echo yes; fi
```

Take also closer look to spaces surrounding brackets.

Comment: Worked for me for my first need but had syntax error afterward for string with spaces (and maybe minus character), for instance with `if [[ $COMMIT_MESSAGE != Merge remote-tracking branch* ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi`, where I had to put double quotes around text: `if [[ $COMMIT_MESSAGE != "Merge remote-tracking branch"* ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have a string in the variable `line` and you want to output the string `yes` if it doesn't start with the character `#`.  In the examples below, I will also output `no` when the condition is not met.

```
case $line in
    "#"*) echo no
esac
```

The `case` statement takes a variable and then any number of (globbing) patterns, and executes the code for the pattern that matches the value of the variable.  In this case we try to match the pattern `"#"*` (the `#` has to be quoted as to not be taken as introducing a comment), and if it matches, an `echo` statement is executed.

If there are more patterns, then the code for all but the last pattern has to be terminated by `;;`, as in

```
case $line in
    "#"*) echo no ;;
    *)    echo yes
esac
```

... and the code for a pattern may be empty:

```
case $line in
    "#"*) ;;
    *)    echo yes
esac
```

The `bash` shell also does pattern matching with globs in `[[ ... ]]` with the `==` operator:

```
if [[ $line != "#"* ]]; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

In `bash`, you may also use regular expression matching with the `=~` operator within `[[ ... ]]`:

```
if ! [[ $line =~ ^# ]]; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

or

```
if [[ $line =~ ^[^#] ]]; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

If you're paring a file line by line, then the shell is not the right tool for that job.  Instead you may want to use something like `awk`:

```
awk '/^[^#]/ { print yes }' <inputfile
```

Related:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)